# Проблема с removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Требуется сделать так чтобы непрочитанные сообщения становились прочитанными. Есть скрипт, но он почему-то не срабатывает, консоль ошибок не выдает. Требуется чтобы у скрипта если он увидел сообщение через определенный интервал удалялся класс `text-sender-unread` и оставался только `text-sender-read`. Вот пример кода:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout;
  $('.message-block').scroll(function() {
    var me = this;
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { //чтобы не искать одно и то же несколько раз
      $(me).find('.text-sender-unread').each(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(me).scrollTop(),
          posTop = $(this).position().top,
          message = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (posTop >= scrollTop && posTop <= scrollTop + $(me).height()) {
            $(message).removeClass('.text-sender-unread');
          }
        }, 1500);
      });
    }, 100);

  }).scrollTop(50);
});
```

```css
.message-block {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #eef2f4;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.text-sender-read {
  background-color: #8bda84;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.text-sender-unread {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 2px #3675d8;
}

.sender {
  position: relative;
}

.sender:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: 96%;
  border-right: 30px solid rgb(139, 218, 132);
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
}

.incoming {
  position: relative;
}

.incoming:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 96%;
  border-left: 30px solid rgb(219, 218, 222);
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 41px solid transparent;
}

.text-incoming {
  background-color: rgba(173, 164, 172, 0.31);
  width: 60%;
  padding: 5%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.page_square_photo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 82%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #b6cada;
  width: 70px;
  /* margin-left: 6px; */
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.page_photos_module {
  padding: 5px 0px 20px;
  height: 110px;
}

.inline-message {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-block">
  <div class="inline-message">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="sender">
        <p class="text-sender-read text-sender-unread">4trew1 yht4rewq 4trew1 yht4rewq 4trew1 yht4rewq 4trew1 yht4rewq </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inline-message">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="incoming">
        <p class="text-incoming"> 4trew1 yht4rewq 4trew1 yht4rewq 4trew1 yht4rewq 4trew1 yht4rewq</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inline-message">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="incoming">
        <p class="text-incoming">ythrgf4ew</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Моя проблема была в синтаксисе, то есть

```
$(message).removeClass('text-sender-unread');
```

`.removeClass()` уже обозначает класс, незачем ставить точку перед `text-sender-unread`, точка обозначает класс, `#` решетка — ид.